# Bundle update gem does nothing although bundle outdated shows the gem

Tags: ruby, rspec, bundler

I have in my `Gemfile`:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

My `Gemfile.lock` says: `rspec-rails (3.3.3)`.

If I run `bundle outdated`, I see:

```
Outdated gems included in the bundle:
* rspec-rails (newest 3.4.0, installed 3.3.3) in groups "development, test"
```

But if I run `bundle update rspec-rails`, nothing happens, it says `Bundle updated!` and the gem version is still the old one `Using rspec-rails 3.3.3`.

What am I doing wrong and how can I update this gem?

Answer (score 0):

Your `bundle update rspec-rails` should work. I just tested myself and it worked fine. But, you can try specifying the version number explicitly in your `Gemfile`:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '3.4.0'
end
```

and then:

```
bundle install
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: I know, but I don't want to have any fixed version for this gem in my `Gemfile`. And regarding the problem, I know `bundle update rspec-rails` should work, but...it doesn't.

Comment: `bundle update rspec-rails` works very well on my system. I tried that too. Try that after uninstalling the gem.

Comment: I ended up by removing my `Gemfile.lock`, and running `bundle`. The gem finally got updated, but I still didn't get what was the initial problem.

Comment: Could it be that on of the many `rspec-rails` dependencies was locked to another version, so bundle update couldn't just update it?